# Java young gc not get invoked before cms remark with CMSScavengeBeforeRemark setting though

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I found a strange phenomenon that java young gc not get invoked before CMS-remark with **-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark** setting though:
[image]

**But most of the time, it is indeed invoked**. I wonder if I can consider that java young gc won't get invoked in a certain situation (for a unknown reason).
  Though the rate of this sort of stuff is really low, the result is not welcome cause you can see it costs 4 seconds in CMS-remark without a young gc invoked before. So, am I right ?

Comment: i think the preclean abort is the problem, not the young GC. user time seems to be 2* wall time. so maybe you should bump the amount of concurrent gc threads?

Comment: @the8472 seems that number of gc thread is not enough. So clever you are.